# create a tar.gz file using C

Tags: c, linux

Hello guys i want to create tar.gz file  from a c 
program

I tried `system("tar -zcvf file.tar.gz file")` but it didn't work. Is there any better alternative you could do. This is my code

```
int make_tar() {
    char buff[100];
    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    d = opendir(".");

    if (d) {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
          if (dir->d_type == DT_REG) {
             sprintf(buff,"%s",dir->d_name);
             system("tar -zxvf buff.tar.xz buff");
         }
    }
    closedir(d);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Read the man-page of `tar`.

Comment: I'm guessing the file 'buff' doesn't exist.

Comment: nope i declared it as char buff[100]

Comment: @Jagdish That's not a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing

```
        sprintf(buff,"%s",dir->d_name);
        system("tar -zxvf buff.tar.xz buff");
```

with

```
if (snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "tar -czvf %s.tar.gz %s", 
         dir->name, dir->name) /// possible code injection!
    >= sizeof(buff)) 
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

fflush(NULL);
int err = system(buff);
if (err) {
   fprintf(stderr, "command failed: %s (%d)\n", buff, err);
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
else printf ("did %s\n", buff);
```

might be helpful. You should use [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) (avoid `sprintf` !!) to avoid [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow), and you need to put the actual name of the file in the command (not `buff`).

You'll better declare `buff`  to contain more characters, e.g. `char buff[512];` or even `static char buff[2*PATH_MAX+25];` (that could be more than 8 kilobytes) or `char buff[2*NAME_MAX+30];`  or use [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html)

Read also about [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection), this will make you be scared of your code. Imagine a malicious user of your program having a file named `foo ; rm -rf ..` (since file names can contain spaces, semicolons, dashes and dots)..

You should consider [using `libtar`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24895219/using-libtar-library-in-c) ...

You should read more about [tar(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html) and might also consider passing the `-T` i.e. `--files-from=`*FILE*  option to it (and have your program construct a temporary textual file listing each file to backup, one per line; this won't be good for filenames with a newline in them).

Comment: I suggest to mention that ```buff``` should be ```NAME_MAX + 1``` bytes here (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/dirent.h.html)

Comment: Err, not ```NAME_MAX + 1```, but ```NAME_MAX * 2 + N```. But ```PATH_MAX``` is an overkill here.

Comment: Indeed, but `PATH_MAX` is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Change your sprintf and your system call

```
sprintf(buff,"tar -zcvf buff.tar.xz %s",dir->d_name);
system(buff);
```

I'm guessing you want to tar the directory which has been found.