# In C on a *nix system, find a binary's absolute path with $PATH or "which"?

Tags: c, linux

I'm looking to get the absolute path of a binary (specifically 7zip's 7z). I think this could be done by either

1. getting the $PATH environment variable, and checking existence of 7z in each of the directories, or
2. "shelling out" to the which command and reading from its stdout.

Which method is the most conventional?

Comment: I'd tend to `which`. AFAIK, it's `$PATH` in *nix anyway and why use that  self-built method if there's even a program specifically for that purpose?

Comment: Please explain and motivate why you need to get the absolute path of a `7z` binary;  I am guessing it is wrong (or very unusual, unless you are coding a shell and its program hash table)

Comment: The idea was to let the user specify the absolute path to the binary in a configuration file, and to provide a default value based on $PATH. But I think I'll reconsider this design based on your information below, probably to use execvp(3) by default unless the configuration file overrides this.

Thank you!

Comment: `execvp` will do what you expect if passed an absolute program path like `/usr/local/bin/which` so you can *always* use `execvp` without checking anything.

Comment: Why your program needs `7z` ? It is a quite unusual requirement and I suggest you to avoid needing it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first method (using `getenv("PATH")` and scanning it....) is preferable and more efficient... This is often what `which` *usually* does (but don't depend on `which` whose behavior can vary a lot...)  but you won't [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) any process (and `fork` or `system` or `which` may fail).

However, I question why you need to find the path of some executable. You could simply use [execvp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html) (and similar `exec*p*` functions, all of them doing the equivalent of `getenv("PATH")`, then scanning it like you would, internally before [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)) when executing that program.

<sup>(In very pathological cases which you are right to ignore, the `getenv("PATH")` could fail)</sup>

Notice that the binary [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) could be removed (or added, or corrupted...) between the moment when you test its existence (and find it in `PATH`) and the moment you are [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)-ing it. And that `execve` can fail (rarely) for many reasons, or not work as you expect (in particular, if some shared library on which your `7z` executable depends is corrupted or removed).

Don't forget that on Linux, several processes could read and write (or execute) the same file (which could also be *removed* or *renamed* while it is read). Please read more about [i-nodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode).

<sup>Hence, finding the full path of `7z` before `execvp`-ing it is wrong -or inaccurate: some other program could have removed or reinstalled `7z` after the path check and before its  [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html). I don't understand why you want to scan the `PATH`, and I believe it is generally useless, leave that to `execvp`</sup>

See also [wordexp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html), [glob(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html), [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html)

Since most software on Linux distributions are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), you can (and perhaps you should) study their source code. For `which` it is often a builtin of your shell (and `bash`, [`zsh`](http://zsh.org/), [`fish`](http://fishshell.com/) are all free software), or a program from [debianutils](https://packages.debian.org/source/sid/debianutils) (perhaps not [coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html)), and I am not sure that most distributions have it (and some of them won't install it by default).

PS. My feeling is that your code should not use `7z` which is usually not available on most Linux systems - and not on my systems; you are perhaps implicitly requiring your user to install it (at least document that). You might prefer `tar` archives to `zip` ones, notice that [tar.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/tar.h.html) is a POSIX header! See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24895219/using-libtar-library-in-c) question and consider `libtar`

Comment: I could have sworn there was a standard library routine to do the path search of `execvp` (etc) but not do the `exec` but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: AFAIK, not in the standard library

Comment: I added a link to the `which` source code. Hope that's OK. It bears out your point.

Comment: You link is to some apple code, not some GNU code. So I removed the link

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Uh? Why?

Comment: Because the question is tagged Linux, and its `which` is generally from coreutils, not from Apple code (at least on most distributions)

Comment: The OP is likely after an approach rather than a code to copy and paste. Seeing as both Linux and Darwin are POSIX complaint systems, and the implementation of `which` on OS X is almost certainly from BSD anyway, it's probably entirely relevant.

Comment: @marko feel free to add a comment with example code

Comment: In many shells, `which` is a builtin

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: `which` is not from coreutils.  On Debian-based systems, it's part of the `debianutils` package.  On CentOS (based on Red Hat), it's provided by the `which` package. On some systems, `which` attempts to search for shell aliases. (For interactive use, if you're using a Bourne-based shell such as bash, `type` is probably better.)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: In csh, tcsh, and zsh; not in bash or ksh.  I've found that the behavior of `which` varies so much that it's not really worth using.  In bash, `type` is more reliable.  In tcsh, the built-in `where` gives more information.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I put the BSD licensed code in as a link as it was the more permissive licence. It should still work on Linux.