# How to write multiple in-memory files to one archive file in C?

Tags: c, tar

I need to concatenate several in-memory files to one "standard" (not my own) archive file format using the C language. Compression is not important but it should be one file, i.e. a `.tar` file. As a result I need to write this archive file to `stdout`.

In C# I usually use the `System.IO.Packaging` namespace, but now I need to use C. Most of the examples describe compressing entities of filesystem, but I can't just use the `tar` utility because I have data in `unsigned char *` variables, not on disk. I know [libtar](https://github.com/tklauser/libtar) can help, but all of the examples I have found use temporal files. I'd like to find a solution that does not create temporal files.

Answer (score 2):

`tar` *should* be an append-only format. I believe you can use [any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24895219/using-libtar-library-in-c) of the `libtar` examples except use [`tar_fdopen`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/tar_fdopen) with `STDOUT_FILENO` for `fd`...